# Cannot refer to the static enum field within an initializer?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I just got Java5 project that has this error, i tried using Java5 and Java6, but its still there. it worked somehow before(since it was in svn), how can i bypass that compiler error?

Comment: It might help to post your code that's erroring

Comment: Could you provide a small code sample of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry to up this, I found it via google, but it seems to work when the private static final field is a primitive type. Does anyone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Don't "bypass" the error - it won't do what you want it to. The error is there for good reason.

The enum values are initialized before any other static fields. If you want to do something like adding all the values into a map, do it in a static initializer *after* everything else:

```
import java.util.*;

public enum Foo
{
    BAR, BAZ;

    private static final Map<String, Foo> lowerCaseMap;

    static
    {
        lowerCaseMap = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
        for (Foo foo : EnumSet.allOf(Foo.class))
        {
            // Yes, use some appropriate locale in production code :)
            lowerCaseMap.put(foo.name().toLowerCase(), foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon - do you know why this error doesn't occur in Eclipse 3.3 but does in 3.4?

Comment: Is there are reason in the example above for using `Foo foo : EnumSet.allOf(Foo.class)` instead of `Foo foo : Foo.values()`?

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly: Not really. They're pretty much equivalent here, I think.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to "bypass" it, if you need for example a counter or something that needs to run on each initalization, is to create a private static inner class, like so:

```
public enum Foo {
    BAR, BAZ;

    private static final class StaticFields {
        private static final Map<String, Foo> lowerCaseMap = new HashMap<>();
        private static int COUNTER = 0;
    }

    private Foo() {
        StaticFields.lowerCaseMap.put(this.name().toLowerCase(), this);
        StaticFields.COUNTER++;
    }
}
```