# illegal reference to static field from initializer

Tags: java, class, oop, enums, static

I am new to enums in java and I am confused as to why this code compiles fine

```
enum Scale5 {
GOOD(), BETTER(), BEST();
static  Scale5 s=GOOD;
}
```

But this code fails:

```
enum Scale5 {
GOOD(), BETTER(), BEST();
Scale5 s=GOOD;
}
```

And I get the error : illegal reference to static field from initializer.
I dont understand the reason.I am relatively inexperienced in enums so please dump it down for me.Thanks a lot!

The question asked here [Cannot refer to the static enum field within an initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536449/cannot-refer-to-the-static-enum-field-within-an-initializer) is the exact opposite of what I have asked.In my case declaring s as static compiles the code just fine.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536449/cannot-refer-to-the-static-enum-field-within-an-initializer

Comment: I have gone through it but could not understand.Its not clear at all

Comment: An instance field cannot reference a static field at the enum level. If it were possible, what are you going to use the variable s?

Comment: @tinker But why cant it refer to a static field when the same is possible here : class X
{
 static X x;
 X y=x;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of an enum like this:

```
public final class Scale5
{
     public static final Scale5 GOOD = new Scale5();
     public static final Scale5 BETTER = new Scale5();
     public static final Scale5 BEST = new Scale5();

     static Scale5 s = GOOD;//works because GOOD is initialized first;
     Scale5 ss = GOOD;//doesn't work because in order to initialize GOOD, 
                      //ss must be assigned an object that is not yet initialized;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Richard.Yes makes sense now.Thanks a lot for dumping it down for me! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2):

> It is a compile-time error to reference a static field of an enum type
>   that is not a constant variable (§4.12.4) from constructors, instance
>   initializer blocks, or instance variable initializer expressions of
>   that type.

Comment: @user3678484 Consider accepting the answer which suits you the best (if any)

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. The first case works because the compiler defines all the enum constants, then initializes static variables. Hence, GOOD at that point already exists and all is fine.

On the second case, the variable exists for all the enum constants, hence, when you are creating GOOD (or BETTER or BEST), GOOD must already be defined and bound. This is of course, illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following example:

```
class X {
    public static final X GOOD = new X();

    X y = GOOD;
    static X z = GOOD;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GOOD);
        System.out.println(GOOD.y);
        System.out.println(X.z);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
X@1db9742
null
X@1db9742
```

As you see value of `GOOD.y` is `null`. That is because at the moment of initializing value of

```
public static final X GOOD = new X();
```

when you invoked `new X()` you ware using current value of `GOOD` which is `null` until `new X()` will be finished. While in case of normal classes this behaviour is allowed, it was forbidden for enums probably because it was too often misunderstood.

In case of static fields they are executed problem dissipaters because they are executed in order of declaration, so

```
static X z = GOOD;
```

will be executed when we are sure that `GOOD` was initialized with proper value.